# How can I use piwik in an ember application?

Tags: ember.js, matomo

Is there any component or plugin that I can use, to integrate piwik into an ember application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple actually. Sadly I haven't found out yet how I can track the individual views. But this will get you going with a basic set-up that also scales well.

Put this in your `ApplicationRoute` it hooks the route's `didTransition` so that every time you transition between routes data gets send to the Piwik server.

```
    actions: {
        didTransition: function () {
            Ember.run.once(this, function () {
                window._paq = _paq || [];
                _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
                _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
                _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', 'https://[Piwik server]/piwik.php']);
                _paq.push(['setSiteId', 1]);
            });
        }
    }
```

And don't forget to put a reference to `Piwik.js` in your application template to load the Piwik tracking library.

```
<script src="https://[Piwik server]/piwik.js" async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an all-integrated solution for Ember like there is for AngularJS.

You can have a look at [this forum thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/analytics-how-to/941/3) which may get you started.

You may also want to have a look at how it's working in AngularJS: http://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/ or https://github.com/mike-spainhower/angular-piwik

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ember-cli-piwik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-piwik). It's quite simple:

Install the addon:

```
ember install ember-cli-piwik
```

Then configure it in your `config/environment.js`

```
piwik: {
  sid: 123,
  url: 'https://your-piwik.endpoint.com'
}
```

For more information, read the docs.